# Is there any method to change filename of the TimedRotatingFileHandler for the "future-created" file in the dictConfig written in JSON?

Tags: python, logging

I would like to change the .suffix for the TimedRotatingFileHandler for the "future-created" file in dictConfig written in json.

Is there any suggestion on how to do that?

JSON file code:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "disable_existing_loggers": true,
  "formatters": {
    "simple": {
      "format": "%(asctime)s-%(levelname)s-%(message)s",
    }
  },
  "handlers": {
    "console":{
      "level": "DEBUG",
      "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
      "formatter": "simple",
      "stream" : "ext://sys.stdout",
    },
    "file": {
      "level": "DEBUG",
      "class": "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
      "when": "s",
      "interval" : 2,
      "backupCount": 3,
      "formatter": "simple",
      "filename": "loggy.log",
      "encoding": "utf-8",
    }
  },
  "loggers": { },
  "root": {
    "handlers": ["console", "file" ],
    "level": "DEBUG"
  }
}
```

Python file code:

```
import logging
import logging.config
from datetime import datetime
import json
import time

with open("logging.json", mode='r') as fd:
    logging.config.dictConfig(json.load(fd))

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

for i in range(9):
    logger.debug('This is a debug message')
    logger.info('This is an info message')
    logger.warning('This is a warning message')
    logger.error('This is an error message')
    logger.critical('This is a critical message')
    time.sleep(10)
```

When I run the code, the debug message stored in log.log for the first 2 seconds, then the next file is having the filename loggy.log.YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS and so on. I would like to know is there any method to change the file name for the next file into YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS.loggy.log? or at least loggy.YYYY-MM-DD_HH_MM_SS.log?

Comment: It's not possible with only using json. You would have to subclass the TimedRotatingFileHandler to replace the naming method.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own TimedRotatingFileHandler class and define your namer method as you like:

```
import logging.handlers
from datetime import date, timedelta


class MyTimedRotatingFileHandler(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, when='midnight', interval=1, backupCount=3):
        super().__init__(filename=filename, when=when, interval=interval, backupCount=backupCount)
        self.namer = rotator_namer


def rotator_namer(filename):
    yesterday = (date.today() - timedelta(1)).isoformat()
    return filename.split('.log')[0] + '_' + yesterday + '.log'
```

In your JSON logger config file you then refer to your MyTimedRotatingFileHandler class:

```
"class": "tools.MyTimedRotatingFileHandler",
```